# Bold italic math fonts with unicode-math (xelatex)

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, boldmath

I don't understand how to get bold italics fonts with unicode maths.
When I load unicode-maths the bold italics from `\boldmaths` becomes normal, and `\mathbf` gives right fonts.

Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math} %works without this
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$x+y=z$

{\boldmath$x+y=z$}

$\mathbf{x+y=z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `mathbfit `

Comment: There is no bold Latin Modern Math font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no bold Latin Modern Math font. You could fake it, but I don't believe it's what you want.

You should recall that `unicode-math` defines `\symbf` which should be used to get a letter in boldface, rather than `\mathbf`, which uses the *text* bold font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}                    
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$x+y=z$

$\symbf{x}+\symbf{y}=\symbf{z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean there's no separate font called "Latin Modern Math Bold", as in a separate font file? LM math does have bold math. (Maybe it is only me confused).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But with LaTeX I usualy used `\newcommand{\gras}[1]{\ifmmode\hbox{\bfseries\boldmath$#1$}\else{\bfseries\boldmath#1}\fi}` to get bold either in text or math mode.
Is it possible to get somethinf like this with `\symbf` ?

Comment: @Oli Do you know about the `bm` package?

Comment: I had a look. But how to use it such as `{\bfseries\boldmath $0123abc$ efg}`: with the `{\cmd abd}` syntax ?

Comment: @Oli Defining `\gras` to do different jobs in math and text is wrong to begin with. Anyway, the usage in `unicode-math` is with `\symbf` and there's not much more to say.

Comment: Thank you. It's more complicated with XeLaTeX and unicode-maths than with "classical" LaTeX ... Strange ...

Answer (score 1):

Aside from egreg's answer, you can always force a certain math bold style by `mathbfup` and `mathbfit` and related `symbf` macros. You can also force `mathbf` to use bold math font instead of text font by the `mathbf=sym` option. See example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={scr,bfscr}]

\begin{document}
\def\sample{0123ABCDabcd\Delta\Gamma\Omega\alpha\beta\gamma}
\[ \sample \]            % normal math
\[ \mathbf{\sample} \]   % default bold symbol
\[ \symbf{\sample} \]    % default bold symbol
\[ \mathbfup{\sample} \] % always upper right bold
\[ \mathbfit{\sample} \] % always italic bold
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But with `\mathbfit` 0123 should be bold too. They are not bold.

Comment: @Oli The font does not have bold italic numbers, and thus you get normal numbers instead. If you need bold math italic numbers, you need to choose a font that has it

Comment: OK. With LaTeX A simple `\boldmath` with `\usepackage{lmodern}` has all this bold fonts ...
So it is strange that Latin Modern does'nt have them with XeLaTeX ...